# Sum $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^{mn}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does this double series has closed form (i.e. can be computed) ?
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^{mn}}$$

Comment: According to Mathematica the result involves the $q$-digamma function (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QPolyGamma.html).

Comment: Hint: First evaluate the inner sum using the geometric series.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trivially

$$\overset{\infty}{\underset{m=1}{\sum}}\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\sum}}\frac{1}{10^{mn}}=\overset{\infty}{\underset{m=1}{\sum}}\frac{1}{10^{m}-1}=-\overset{\infty}{\underset{m=1}{\sum}}\frac{1}{1-10^{m}}$$
 and the last sum can be computed, using the identity$$\overset{\infty}{\underset{m=1}{\sum}}\frac{1}{1-a^{m}}=\frac{\psi_{1/a}\left(1\right)+\log\left(a-1\right)+\log\left(1/a\right)}{\log\left(a\right)}$$
 where$$\psi_{q}\left(z\right)=-\log\left(1-q\right)+\log\left(q\right)\overset{\infty}{\underset{m=0}{\sum}}\frac{q^{n+z}}{1-q^{n+z}}
 $$
 is the q-Polygamma function. Hence$$\overset{\infty}{\underset{m=1}{\sum}}\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\sum}}\frac{1}{10^{mn}}=-\frac{\psi_{1/10}\left(1\right)+\log\left(9\right)+\log\left(1/10\right)}{\log\left(10\right)}\approx0.122324.$$

Comment: You are off by a factor $10$.